# Error When Trying to Create Function Grapher

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, sympy

I am trying to make a program using Python that allows the user to pick a function and graph it over specified values.  I have this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np
from sympy import Symbol, Derivative, sin, sympify
from sympy.core.sympify import SympifyError

x = Symbol('x')

fx = sympify(input("What is your function? "))
x_min = float(input("Enter x minimum: "))
x_max = float(input("Enter x maximum: "))

x_values = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, 3)
y_values = fx.doit().subs({x:x_values})

plt.plot(x_values, y_values)

plt.show()
```

I input x**2 for the function, 0 for x_min, and 3 for x_max.  The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/core/sympify.py", line 178, in sympify
expr = parse_expr(a, locals or {}, rational, convert_xor)
  File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/parsing/sympy_parser.py", line 163, in parse_expr
expr = eval(code, global_dict, local_dict) # take local objects in preference
  File "<string>", line 1
    [Float ('0.' )Float ('1.5' )Float ('3.' )]
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/joe126/Dropbox/Python/Chapter02.py", line 16, in <module>
  File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/core/basic.py", line 831, in subs
so, sn = sympify(o), sympify(n)
  File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/core/sympify.py", line 180, in sympify
raise SympifyError('could not parse %r' % a)
sympy.core.sympify.SympifyError: SympifyError: "could not parse '[0.  1.5 3. ]'"
```

What is going wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: On which line do you get the error? For me your error is not reproducible. The only error I get from your code is a shape mismatch when trying to plot, as `y_values` contains only 1 element which is 'x**2' of `sympy.core.power.Pow` type.

Comment: @Georgy I have edited the question to include the entire error message.

Comment: I still don't understand how the error is related to the given example code and on which line it happens. Try running it [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sympy_terminal_online.php) for example. Paste the code starting from `x = Symbol('x')` until `y_values = fx.doit().subs({x:x_values})`. You will have to import numpy there as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the error. I get the same error as Georgy: a shape mismatch when plotting. But why don't you try using lambdify to evaluate the function like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np
from sympy import Symbol, Derivative, sin, sympify, lambdify
from sympy.core.sympify import SympifyError

x = Symbol('x')

fx = sympify(input("What is your function? "))
x_min = float(input("Enter x minimum: "))
x_max = float(input("Enter x maximum: "))

x_values = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, 3)
fx_lambda = lambdify(x,fx)
y_values = fx_lambda(x_values)

plt.plot(x_values, y_values)

plt.show()
```

[Result for x**2 from 0 to 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SC6xr.png)

Comment: Note that you can calculate `y_values` simply as `fx_lambda(x_values)`

Comment: Also, `"numpy"` is a default argument. So you can omit it.

Comment: Ok! Btw, there is still unnecessary wrapping of `fx_lambda(x_values)` in `np.array`. Just `y_values = fx_lambda(x_values)` would be enough

Comment: I did just copy and paste into elpy, but the error persists.  Your code works just fine.  Thanks.